# Minimize an integral

Tags: calculus, calculus-of-variations

I would like to numerically estimate (and plot) the continous functions $h(x)$ and $p(x)$ in the interval $[x_1;x_2]$, that minimize the following expression:

$$F=\int_{x_1}^{x_2}\frac{1}{1+\left(\frac{p(x)}{x}\right)^{h(x)} } dx$$

where $p(x_1) \leq p(x) \leq p(x_2)$, $h(x)>0$ and $p'(x)>0$. The values are:
$$x_1=4.5$$
$$x_2=14$$
$$p(x_1)=3.5$$
$$p(x_2)=4.6$$
$$h(x_1)=2.8$$
$$h(x_2)=2.4$$

Is it possible to do it in Maple or Mathematica?

Kind regards
Rasmus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can make $F$ as small as I desire. Suppose that for $x>4.51$ and $x<13.99$, I made $p(x)=-1.00000000001\cdot x$ and $h(x)=1$. Do you see the problem?

## Edit

Even after your new conditions, your problem is still broken. Minimizing $F$ requires us to now maximize $p(x)$ and $h(x)$. As $p(x),h(x)\to\infty$, $F\to0$, which is the lower bound for the integral. As such, this question is pointless, because I can always make $p(x)$ and $h(x)$ larger to make $F$ smaller.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can not take $h(x)=1$, but I understand your point. I shound have mentioned that $h(x)>0$ and $p(x)>0$. Furthermore $p'(x)>0$. The question is updated above.

Comment: You're right! One last question. What if we let
$$p(x_1)≤p(x)≤p(x_2)$$
$$h(x_1)≤h(x)≤h(x_2)$$
and
$$h'(x) \leq 0$$
$$p'(x) \geq 0$$
Will that help?

Comment: @RHD No, that won't help. It's actually pretty obvious why. I'll leave this one to you to think about. But the point is, no, that doesn't fix much at all.